# Trying to decrypt a file with AES but get error: Padding is incorrect

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I am given this code that encrypts a string "flag".

```
from Crypto.Util.number import getPrime
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

prime = getPrime(1024)
privkey = random.randint(2, prime - 1)
key = pow(2, privkey, prime)

sk = pow(key, privkey, prime)
aes_key = hashlib.md5(str(sk).encode()).digest()
cipher = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
pt = cipher.encrypt(pad(flag, 16)).hex()
        
print(f"[+] This encrypted flag : {pt}")
```

And I am told to decrypt the encrypted string to get the original string. I am given the values for the encrypted flag and key plus the values for prime and private key (privkey) in hexadecimal. I tried to use those values to decrypt the flag like so:

```
flag = "8fceb2a29cc2d7abd8ecfc8da5dc1eea6f67f7a0b047749d66ef8886bb33c720dfc5dd4e508bd1e4a811c62b83f98e65"

prime = int("0xf9aecd571c9afadaceae0004000c64fceb6720f717756dab1f12b2ed7fd211a13024735efeb80a8f7982a0787d4a2eb866b18b8e7d62f2b92f6bd0d7ca52b2cd18e7b508d1af3c69eee907ab9bde2cca7f6cea613954d98a3f8e0c52761937636afb2b6776ac7f4ac02af12e72f4f4905dbeac3e4e856c8542bbda24106161d9", 16)

privkey = int("0x3e1591ea4e4eef19c99626ab1d15d442becbbd2b7d7a4150ee8f1af3f0adf9df47a53823ddfe83c6a7fa4b1b5dfa319021b26dec15c385d3869c7a7ce039b8519318563602d846ea242550bbac73dfc20a27c19b119820e45589cc6f54e9bafc50befbe222aa2738a35f5fca17ca7eec71ce24449ed21fd46b92ca11080001", 16)

key= 101752188851588702786663864886064578902654651951985866839003796634186954471878272123772894282171928731095228234190527287304860559135921159182420718259970442394992811637314757293507073993913485850566751318782466533493182193918336800513466736844109978537994535285068729297204514757610248021028835645897421370304

sk = pow(key, privkey, prime)
aes_key = hashlib.md5(str(sk).encode()).digest()
cipher = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
ct = unpad(cipher.decrypt(bytes.fromhex(flag)), 16)

print(f"[+] This decrypted flag : {ct}")
```

But this doesn't seem to work since I keep getting

> ValueError: Padding is incorrect.

Which part am I doing incorrectly?

---

**Edit:** Description of `privkey`:

[image]

Comment: The posted values for `prime`, `privkey`, and `key` do not satisfy the equation `key = pow(2, privkey, prime)`. Either the data is incorrect or the ciphertext was generated with a different logic.

Comment: @Topaco Maybe. This is the code they used to encrypt: https://imgur.com/a/vi7Yc2M. And this is the output of that code: https://justpaste.it/9okx5

Comment: So, you need to brute force for the `key`. Are there any given possible ranges? You need to search all possible spaces.

Comment: @kelalaka The key is shown in their output. You can see they entered a key there: justpaste.it/9okx5

Comment: You claim that the ciphertext was generated with the linked encryption code, but you don't provide any proof for this. On the other hand, your own decryption code disproves you, because it cannot decrypt the ciphertext although it is the corresponding decryption code to the linked encryption code (which you can easily verify).

Comment: @Topaco I'm not the one who encrypted it. This is from a hackathon capture the flag where I'm given the encryption code and the output to decrypt the encrypted flag. There might be something wrong with the output that they gave.

Comment: Maybe. Here a link or a 1:1 description of the task would have been more fault-tolerant.

Comment: If the information is read carefully, the problem can be solved, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the decryption code, but an incomplete key `privkey`.

The description of the key in the screenshot as *privkey leaked* together with the two trailing underscores and the information that this is a challenge from a hackathon made me suspect that the key is incomplete, needs to be supplemented by two hex digits, and the full key is to be determined.

This assumption is confirmed if a byte is added to the end of the key whose value runs in a loop from 0 to 255, and PKCS#7 padding is used as criterion for a successful decryption. If this is done, the result is the plaintext:

```
CDDC22{D1ffi3_H3llm4n_k3y_3xch@ng3_D0ne!}
```

and the `privkey`:

```
3e1591ea4e4eef19c99626ab1d15d442becbbd2b7d7a4150ee8f1af3f0adf9df47a53823ddfe83c6a7fa4b1b5dfa319021b26dec15c385d3869c7a7ce039b8519318563602d846ea242550bbac73dfc20a27c19b119820e45589cc6f54e9bafc50befbe222aa2738a35f5fca17ca7eec71ce24449ed21fd46b92ca11080001d6
```

i.e. 0xd6 as final byte

---

Full code:

```py
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

prime = int("0xf9aecd571c9afadaceae0004000c64fceb6720f717756dab1f12b2ed7fd211a13024735efeb80a8f7982a0787d4a2eb866b18b8e7d62f2b92f6bd0d7ca52b2cd18e7b508d1af3c69eee907ab9bde2cca7f6cea613954d98a3f8e0c52761937636afb2b6776ac7f4ac02af12e72f4f4905dbeac3e4e856c8542bbda24106161d9", 16)
privkey = int("0x3e1591ea4e4eef19c99626ab1d15d442becbbd2b7d7a4150ee8f1af3f0adf9df47a53823ddfe83c6a7fa4b1b5dfa319021b26dec15c385d3869c7a7ce039b8519318563602d846ea242550bbac73dfc20a27c19b119820e45589cc6f54e9bafc50befbe222aa2738a35f5fca17ca7eec71ce24449ed21fd46b92ca1108000100", 16)
key= 101752188851588702786663864886064578902654651951985866839003796634186954471878272123772894282171928731095228234190527287304860559135921159182420718259970442394992811637314757293507073993913485850566751318782466533493182193918336800513466736844109978537994535285068729297204514757610248021028835645897421370304
ct = "8fceb2a29cc2d7abd8ecfc8da5dc1eea6f67f7a0b047749d66ef8886bb33c720dfc5dd4e508bd1e4a811c62b83f98e65"

for val in range(255):

    sk = pow(key, privkey, prime)
    aes_key = hashlib.md5(str(sk).encode()).digest()
    cipher = AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    try: 
        ptPadded = cipher.decrypt(bytes.fromhex(ct)) 
        pt = unpad(ptPadded, 16)
        print(f"[+] This decrypted flag (padded)      : {ptPadded}")
        print(f"[+] This decrypted flag (unpadded)    : {pt}")
        print(f"[+] This decrypted flag (UTF8 decoded): {pt.decode('utf8')}")
        print(f"[+] privkey (hex)                     : {(privkey).to_bytes(128, byteorder='big').hex()}")
    except:
        pass
    
    privkey += 1
```

Output:

```
[+] This decrypted flag (padded)      : b'CDDC22{D1ffi3_H3llm4n_k3y_3xch@ng3_D0ne!}\n\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06\x06'
[+] This decrypted flag (unpadded)    : b'CDDC22{D1ffi3_H3llm4n_k3y_3xch@ng3_D0ne!}\n'
[+] This decrypted flag (UTF8 decoded): CDDC22{D1ffi3_H3llm4n_k3y_3xch@ng3_D0ne!}

[+] privkey (hex)                     : 3e1591ea4e4eef19c99626ab1d15d442becbbd2b7d7a4150ee8f1af3f0adf9df47a53823ddfe83c6a7fa4b1b5dfa319021b26dec15c385d3869c7a7ce039b8519318563602d846ea242550bbac73dfc20a27c19b119820e45589cc6f54e9bafc50befbe222aa2738a35f5fca17ca7eec71ce24449ed21fd46b92ca11080001d6
```

Comment: SO, this is a CTF and OP was hiding...